# Facebook iOS SDK [NSNull count]: unrecognized selector crash BIG

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk, crash

Issue started about 11:20 UK time, and it affects many big applications like spotify, waze, medium and so on.

It looks like it related with event managers and analytics. Some of the apps that crashed 10 min ago, seems working now.

Can it be solved by changing any facebook dev settings?
Anyone able to solve it without waiting Facebook to solve?

For more info:

https://developers.facebook.com/status/issues/1739188102911114/

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/issues/1430

https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/329763701368293/

```
4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23e43bf8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   FBSDKCoreKit                        0x000000010f736f3a +[FBSDKRestrictiveDataFilterManager updateFilters:] + 62
    6   FBSDKCoreKit                        0x000000010f739a0c +[FBSDKServerConfigurationManager processLoadRequestResponse:error:appID:] + 1912
    7   FBSDKCoreKit                        0x000000010f739281 __78+[FBSDKServerConfigurationManager loadServerConfigurationWithCompletionBlock:]_block_invoke + 62
    8   FBSDKCoreKit                        0x000000010f729110 -[FBSDKGraphRequestMetadata invokeCompletionHandlerForConnection:withResults:error:] + 143
    9   FBSDKCoreKit                        0x000000010f7269fe __82-[FBSDKGraphRequestConnection processResultBody:error:metadata:canNotifyDelegate:]_block_invoke + 142
    10  FBSDKCoreKit                        0x000000010f72690d -[FBSDKGraphRequestConnection processResultBody:error:metadata:canNotifyDelegate:] + 636
    11  FBSDKCoreKit                        0x000000010f72654d __64-[FBSDKGraphRequestConnection completeWithResults:networkError:]_block_invoke + 398
```

Comment: it seems it fixed.

Answer (score 1):

1. From my side, in the response, there is `null` value. Yes!!! `null` is a kind of primitive type in [`JSON` specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627).
   [image]
2. Then after FB using `[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: options: error:]` to serialize this object, it returns `NSNull` object without error. According to Apple's doc, `NSNull` is a singleton object. Yes!!!, it is a valid object, not like `nil`, which you can guard using `if (obj)` statement
   [image]
3. So, when FB try to use `if (serializedObj) { ... }` to guard this edge cases in many places, it is actually useless. Here `serializedObj` is a singleton object, the result is YES then it continues to send message, then, `unrecoginized selector` .  This issue haven't been fixed now. Next time, when the server side sends an another object with `null`, we will see another disaster.

---

Updated:
`FB` is trying to fix this [issue](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/commit/b1ec939cb994dbcf85b495ec747753289271f105)